# OnClicking Delete an Item from the ListView in Android

Tags: android, list, listview

I am trying to implement Delete functional to delete item from the listview. Click On the Text "Remove Item" Item should be removed from the ListView.
I have tried but, I am getting an error in the code.
I dont have any Idea of how to correct the errors.

Here is my code:

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {


      final  ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selecteditemlistview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textViewSelectedText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectedtext);
            holder.price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemprice);
            holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemimage);
            holder.qty=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectqty);
            holder.total=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);

            holder.deleteButton = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String amount=holder.qty.getText().toString();
        final Double price1=Double.parseDouble(itemprice.get(position));
        int qut=Integer.parseInt(holder.qty.getText().toString());
        Double total=(price1*qut);
        holder.textViewSelectedText.setText(arr1.get(position));
        holder.price.setText(itemprice.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(itemimage.get(position));
        holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(total));

        final CartItem mCartItem = (CartItem) getItem(position);


        holder.mTextView.setText(mCartItem.product_name);
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                Object cartItems;
                CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomAdapter.this, R.layout.selecteditemlistview, cartItems);
                ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.delete);
                listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                        cartItems.remove(object);
                        myAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();


            }

        });

        return convertView;     
    }

    class ViewHolder      
    {
         public TextView deleteButton;
         public TextView mTextView;

        TextView textViewSelectedText = null;
        TextView price=null;
        ImageView image=null;      
        EditText qty=null;
        TextView total=null;
    }  
    public class CartItem {
        public int id;
        public String product_name;
    }
```

The Exact error is in the below code:

```
     holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                Object cartItems;
                CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomAdapter.this, R.layout.selecteditemlistview, cartItems);
                ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.delete);
                listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                Object toRemove = arrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]);
                arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);

            }

        });
```

Please Help me to solve this problem. Thank you..

This are my Logcat errors:

```
       05-18 12:38:04.630: I/System.out(514): Printing
       05-18 12:38:04.711: I/System.out(514): [152.00]
       05-18 12:38:04.711: I/System.out(514): arr: 1
       05-18 12:38:04.721: I/System.out(514): 152.0
       05-18 12:38:04.781: D/AndroidRuntime(514): Shutting down VM
       05-18 12:38:04.781: W/dalvikvm(514): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at com.customer.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:106)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at  android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
       05-18 12:38:04.811: E/AndroidRuntime(514):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? post your logcat error message

Comment: I dint run my Application. In the code I am getting an error.

Comment: The errors are like: Multiple markers at this line
 - cartItems cannot be resolved to a variable
 - MyAdapter cannot be resolved to a type
 - MyAdapter cannot be resolved to a type
 - The constructor CustomAdapter(CustomAdapter, int, Object) is 
  undefined

Comment: OK. are you using ArrayList to populate you List. what are the values for itemprice and arr1. Can you post your entire adapter class for a little clearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is simply remove the dataset item from which you are populating your Adapter and then notify the adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 yourdataset.remove(position);
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: As I am new to Stack Overflow Can u plz tell me how to post a errors ??

Comment: This is the error :at com.customer.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:106)

Comment: and that line is the : final CartItem mCartItem = (CartItem) getItem(position);

Comment: @Stuthi as you are new to StackOverflow, If you are satisfied with the answer you should check mark it so that other users don't answer this again thinking this as an unanswered question.